# How to know type of object in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am doing an application in NetLogo and would like to know if there is something to know the data type of a variable, something similar to instanceof in JAVA.

```
to main
 move blockA
end

to move [block]
 ;;;how to know if block is xty BlockA or BlockB???
end
```

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, `BlockA` and `BlockB` are turtle breeds, yes? There are two ways:

I'll assume your breeds are declared as:

```
breed [ BlockAs BlockA ]
breed [ BlockBs BlockB ]
```

1. `[ breed ] of block` will report it's breed, so you can do, for instance, `if [ breed ] of block = BlockAs [ ... ]` or `ask block [ if breed = BlockAs [ ... ] ]`.
2. The [`is-*?`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#is-of-type) primitives. In the case of turtle breeds, you can do `is-BlockA? block`. This also works for other data types. For instance `is-number?` will tell you if something is a number.